# Rails scraping - submitting a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I am filling in a form on a page and submitting it.
This should trigger the download of a file.

However, when I try to save the output of the download, I get the source code of the page rather than the file.

My code is:

```
mechanize = Mechanize.new
mechanize.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download

page = mechanize.get('http://page.com/')

form = page.forms.first
form.radiobuttons_with(name: 'presence')[0].check
form.source = "btce"
form.label = "BTC/USD"

mechanize.get_file(form.submit).save!('page.csv')
```

How can I save a file which is downloaded when I submit a form?

Answer (score 0):

Does the file automatically begin downloading once you submit the form?
Submitting a form may return a new page, also new scripts/stylesheets can be loaded. Which possibly explains why your file contains the source code since that's what you're downloading. (Mechanize doesn't throw an error if you download a web page)

For example, I use Mechanize to fill out Google's search form and submit it and save the results to `google_search.csv`. The new file contains a mixture of the page's source code along with javascript, mySQL, and its stylesheets.

You can dig through the page's source code using Firebug and pinpoint what exactly happens when you submit the form, which can likely be a link that's invoked but you were unaware of.